# Strings in C (strstr function)

Tags: c, c-strings, function-definition, strstr

I'm trying to reproduce the behavior of the `strstr()` function, which tries to find a substring in a string and for that I created the following function and compared it to the original. I did the iterations all on paper to understand what was going on in the function, but I don't understand why the command `return (&str[i]);` prints `ab` and not just `a`. When the function enters in `if (to_find[j] == '\0')`, the values of `i` and `j` are `2` and `2`, so it should just print `&str[2]`, which is `a`. Why is printing `ab` instead of just `a`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

char    *ft_strstr(char *str, char *to_find)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    i = 0;
    if (*to_find == '\0')
        return (str);
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        j = 0;
        while (str[i + j] == to_find[j])
        {
            //printf("%d", i);
            //printf("%d\n", j);
            j++;
            if (to_find[j] == '\0')
                return (&str[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}

int main()
{
    char i[] = "ab";
    char dest[] = "a ab";
    printf("%s", ft_strstr(dest, i));
    //printf("%s", strstr(dest, i));
}
```

Comment: printf print till founding a `'0` for `"%s"` perhaps you want to print just a char with `"%c"`

Comment: The function returns a `char *` and not `char`. So, `printf` will treat it as a null terminated string

Comment: I recommend you draw a rectangle on a piece of paper, then divide it into four sub-rectangles. In each sub-rectangle you fill in the letter of the string `dest`. The draw an arrow to the first letter and label that arrow `str`. Now draw a second arrow to the third letter and label it `&str[2]`. Each of the two arrows represents the important pointers pointers in your `ft_strstr` function, and each of them are a pointer to null-terminated sequence of characters, a.k.a. *a string*.

Answer (score 2):

`return (&str[i]);` What this does is:

- `str[i]` this is the same as `*(str+i)`. It means take the address where `str` points to, add `i` to it and get its value.
- `&x` means get the address of `x`
- `(&str[i])` Is a combination of the 2 above. It means take the address where `str` points to, add `i` to it and get its value and then get the address of that value. Which means the last 2 steps cancel each other out and you get: take the address where `str` points to, add `i` to it. It is the same as `(str+i)`.
- The return statement just means return this pointer.

Now after you called `ft_strstr(dest, i)` you get this pointer. In your case this pointer points to the second a in the string `"a ab"`. You give this pointer to `printf()` and with the `"%s"` you told `printf()` to print the string where this pointer points to till there is a `'\0'`-byte. `'b'` is not a `'\0'`-byte so it will also be printed.

The returned pointer points to here when you call `printf()`:

```
          V
+---+---+---+---+---+
| a |   | a | b |\0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

`printf()` will then check if it points to a `'\0'`-byte, which is false so the byte (`'a'`) is printed and the pointer is incremented. Then the same is done for the byte (`'b'`) and then it points to `'\0'`, which means `printf()` stops here.

Answer (score 1):

When you print the return value from `strstr` using the specifier `%s` it will print "the needle" (aka the string to find) and **all** of the original string **after** the needle.

In your case there is nothing after the needle so your output is just "ab". Had your original string been "a abHelloWorld" your output would have been "abHelloWorld".

If you just want the first character of the needle do:

```
printf("%c", *ft_strstr(dest, i));
```

Also you can try this to get a better understanding:

```
char str[] = "Hello World";
printf("%s\n", str);
printf("%s\n", &str[0]);
printf("%s\n", &str[1]);
printf("%s\n", &str[2]);
printf("%s\n", &str[3]);
...
```

which will give you output

```
Hello World
Hello World
ello World
llo World
lo World
...
```

As you can see, printing from `&str[n]` will skip the first N characters and print the rest of the original string.

BTW:

```
char    *ft_strstr(char *str, char *to_find)
```

should be

```
char    *ft_strstr(const char *str, const char *to_find)
```

Answer (score 1):

`return (&str[i]);` does not print anything. It just returns a value. And the value is the address to the i:th element of str.

The printing happens in `printf("%s", ft_strstr(dest, i));` and what happens here is that you start with a format string, and the `%s` is a specifier that basically says "print characters until hitting the zero terminator, and start with the address specified".

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%s", ...)` prints a string, not a single character. To print a character, use the `%c` format specifier and provide the first element of the array as the argument:

```
printf("%c", *ft_strstr(dest, i));
```

Another option is to use `putchar(...)` for printing a single character.

For more information on `printf` format specifiers, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Answer (score 0):

Within this while loop

```
    while (str[i + j] == to_find[j])
    {
        //printf("%d", i);
        //printf("%d\n", j);
        j++;
        if (to_find[j] == '\0')
            return (&str[i]);
    }
```

the variable `i` is not being changed. It stays unchanged. It is the variable `j` that is being changed.

On the other hand the return statement

```
return (&str[i]);
```

returns a pointer to the symbol at the position `i` that is to the beginning of the substring equal to the string `to_find`.

{ay attention to that the array `dest` declared like

```
char dest[]="a ab";
```

in fact has the following content

```
char dest[] = { 'a', ' ', 'a', 'b', '\0' };
```

and the function returns a pointer to its substring

```
char dest[] = { 'a', ' ', 'a', 'b', '\0' };
                           ^
                           |
                        { 'a', 'b', '\0' }
```

that is a pointer to the first character of the string `"ab"` that is a substring of the string stored in the array `dest`.

Bear in main that when you write for example

```
printf( "%s\n", dest );
```

when this call is equivalent to

```
int i = 0;
printf( "%s\n", &dest[i] );
```